# java.sql.SQLException: General error

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, odbc, database-connection

Getting `java.sql.SQLException`

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6986)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:253)
at com.test.Temp.main(Temp.java:29)
```

I am using following code

```
Connection con=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement stmt=null;

try {
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:locator","locator","locator");

  stmt=con.createStatement();
  System.out.println("Before query");
  String query=null;
  query="select * from user_location_table";
  System.out.println("after query12");

  rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
  //perform certain operation....
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  con.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception is thrown at `stmt.executeQuery(query)`.

user_location_table contains following fields

```
user_id:number  not null,
latitude:number,
longitude:number,
update_time:timestamp(6)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is likely due to an error when accessing the database. Does it happen consistently? Have you ensured the database connection details are correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get it.

The error is thrown due to the use of datatype timestamp(6) in update_time.The exception is thrown whenever we try to execute the select statement containing a column with timestamp as the datatype.

Instead of the previous code we can use the following code for selecting

```
    query="select latitude,longitude,to_char(update_time,'HH24:MI:SS'),to_char(update,time,'DD-MON-YY') from user_location_table";
```

This works fine,I have tested it.

Cheers!!

Comment: You should use a **real** JDBC driver instead of the JDBC/ODBC bridge. Oracle's "native" JDBC does not have problems with a timestamp column. The JDBC/ODBC bridge is buggy (as you have just discovered) and slow.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts. If it's only happening on the first execute, it may be that there is something invalid in the db and it's being compiled. Secondly, you may have something leaking because you aren't closing your connection and statement in a finally block. So if you get an exception, you aren't closing the connections and potentially you're creating a lock on your DB.

Add a finally block and move your close statements there checking for null:

```
try {
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:locator","locator","locator");

  stmt=con.createStatement();
  System.out.println("Before query");
  String query=null;
  query="select * from user_location_table";
  System.out.println("after query12");

  rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
  //perform certain operation....

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
  try {
    if (rs!=null)
      rs.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  try {
      if (stm!=null)
        stmt.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  try {
    if (con!=null)
      con.close();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```